# Genus der Flüsse: eine komische Regel

Tags: gender

Im Grammatikbuch *Hammer's German Grammar and  Usage* habe ich eben  gelesen , dass Flüsse im Ausland männlich sind:

> der Ganges
>   der Nil

Im Gegenteil sind die Flüsse innerhalb Deutschlands feminin

> die Maas
>   die Donau

Könnte mir ein Benutzer etwas über die Herkunft und Logik dieser amüsanten Regel erklären? Und wie steht es mit Flüssen in der Schweiz, Österreich,... ?

*Edit* Weiter im Buch wird  die Ausnahme erwähnt, dass ausländische Flüsse mit Endung *-a*  oder *-e* feminin sind: *die Seine, die Wolga*

Comment: Es gibt keine solche Regel: der Rhein, die Wolga. Außerdem fließt die Maas nach heutigen Grenzen nicht durch Deutschland.

Comment: @Stefan: Erst nach meinem Editieren habe ich Dein Kommentar gelesen: was *die Wolga* betrifft sind wir also völlig einverstanden. Und *der Rhein* ist unbestreitbar männlich! Ist er die einzige Ausnahme? Oder sind vielleicht die meisten deutschen Flüsse doch männlich? Das wäre trotzdem interessant. Selbst eine statistische Faustregel hilft, finde ich, wenn man Deutsch spricht, verglichen mit blindem Raten. Ich bin an  Deine eventuellen weiteren Kommentare  oder Antwort sehr interessiert.

Comment: @Georges: Der Lech und der Regen sind Nebenflüsse der Donau, die aber nicht vollständig in Deutschland liegen.

Comment: Viele Flüsse fließen durch mehrere Länder, zumal, wenn man den Grenzverlauf verschiedener Jahrhunderte ansieht. Die Mosel fließt ein Stück durch Frankreich, der Rhein durch Schweiz und Holland, die ganzen Grenzflüsse nicht zu vergessen. Der Main allerdings kommt mir sehr kerndeutsch vor, und ist männlich. Eine Faustregel, die ständig falsch liegt, hilft m.e. nichts. Die Themse, die Seine, die Spree=> Flüsse, die durch Hauptstädte fließen?

Comment: Den *Neckar* nicht vergessen! Nirgends fließt dieser auch nur ansatzweise außerhalb Deutschlands.

Comment: Die folgenden deutschen Flüsse (über 100 km Länge) sind männlich: Rhein, Main, Inn, Lech, Neckar, Koch, Regen und Rhin. Alle anderen sind weiblich.

Comment: Der Rio Grande (in jedem besseren spanischsprachigem Land) ist auch männlich und wieder eine Ausnahme der Ausnahme.

Comment: @userunknown: Das kann man denke ich auf alle Flüsse, die einfach "Río-irgendwas" heißen, verallgemeinern.

Comment: Ich vermute, bei _Koch_ im Kommentar von @Ingmar war eine Autokorrektur am Werk. Gemeint ist der _Kocher_, ein Nebenfluß des Neckars.

Comment: In Österreich kommen noch der Kamp und der Ziller als maskuline Flussnamen hinzu.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Wie [Stefan Walter in seiner Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1933/genus-der-flusse-eine-komische-regel/1934#1934) bereits erläutert hat, existiert die Regel nicht.

Allerdings stimmt es, dass viele deutsche Flussnamen weiblich sind. Es gibt einige wenige männliche Flussnamen. Sie sind meist vorgermanischen Ursprungs: "der Rhein", "der Main", "der Inn", "der Neckar", "der Eisack", "der Lech", "der Regen". Diese Namen haben ein maskulines Geschlecht, da in vorgermanischer Zeit die Flüsse als verkörperte (männliche) Götter betrachtet wurden.

Der Namensforscher Konrad Kunze, Professor am Deutschen Seminar der Universität Freiburg, [schreibt Folgendes](http://www.wissenschaft-im-dialog.de/aus-der-forschung/wieso/detail/article/wie-kamen-fluesse-zu-ihren-artikeln-die-weser-die-elbe-der-main-der-inn-die-donau-der-nil-w.html?tx_ttnews%5BbackPid%5D=87&cHash=c8a89c8bb5) zu diesem Thema:

> Die Flussnamen in unserem Raum ("Deutschland") waren und sind in der Regel weiblich, wie das alte Wort "die Ach" = 'der Fluss', weswegen Namen mit -ach weiblich sind (die Wutach, die Brigach, die Schwarzach usw.). auch 'der Bach' war früher und ist heute noch in vielen Dialekten weiblich, die Bach, niederdeutsch die Beeke. Daher heißt es in alten Formulierungen noch heute z.B. "die Schlacht an der Katzbach".  Auch andere Flussnamen unseres Raumes sind weiblich, vgl. die Fulda, die Elbe, die Weser, die Havel, die Saale usw. usw. Das kann mit dem grammatischen Geschlecht der Wörter zusammenhängen, die in den Flussnamen stecken.
>
> Früher meinte man, es käme davon, dass die Menschen in den Flüssen weibliche Gottheiten gesehen hätten, Nixen usw.-  Namen, die sehr alt sind und aus vordeutschen Sprachen stammen, sind oft männlich, und die entsprechenden Gottheiten auch männlich dargestellt: der Vater Nil, der Flussgott Tiber, und so auch der Rhein, aus lateinisch/keltisch Rhenus, der Inn aus lateinisch und älter Aenus, der Main aus lat. und älter Moenus, der Lech aus lat. und älter Licus usw.
>
> Einige von ihnen haben nach dem Vorbild der meisten hier befindlichen Flussnamen später das weibliche Geschlecht angenommen, so ist aus männlichem Saravus heute die weibliche Saar geworden, aus dem männlichen Danubius heute die weibliche Donau (wohl in Angleichung an das Wort die Au(e)), aus dem männlichen Rhodanus heute die weibliche Rhone.Bei anderen sehr alten Namen ist das männliche Geschlecht erhalten geblieben, der Inn, der Lech usw.

Das Geschlecht von Flussnamen wurde vor sehr langer Zeit festgelegt – teilweise in der indoeuropäischen Grundsprache bereits um 1000 v. Chr., also vor der Entwicklung der germanischen Sprache.

Gewässernamen entstanden aus dem ursprünglichen Wortstamm, kombiniert mit einer Endung für das Geschlecht. Die schlichteste Form der Gewässernamen ist die, dass an ein wurzelhaftes Element ein einfaches, den Flexionsnamen abgebendes -a antritt, so dass feminine Gebilde entstehen wie Aisa und Isa, Nida und Neida. (*Quelle: (H. Krahe, Unsere ältesten Flußnamen, Wiesbaden 1964)*)

Comment: Dieser Reichtum an Information ist ein  Genuss: vielen Dank, splattne! Jetzt verstehe ich, im Licht der Mythologie, warum es einen Unterschied gibt zwischen den deutschen und den anderen Flüssen.

Answer (score 18):

Es gibt keine solche Regel.

Männliche Flüsse in Deutschland: Der Rhein, der Inn, der Lech, der Main, der Neckar.

Weibliche Flüsse in Deutschland: Die Elbe, die Donau, die Weser, die Isar, die Ruhr, die Spree, die Havel, die Oder.

Vom Gefühl her würde ich sagen, dass es mehr weibliche als männliche gibt, vielleicht 75:25 oder noch mehr, denn im Moment fallen mir keine männlichen deutschen Flüsse mehr ein, aber zahlreiche weibliche.

Ich denke, dass Flüsse, die auf a oder e enden, fast immer weiblich sind. Ansonsten fürchte ich, dass es keine tauglichen Regeln gibt. Bei ausländischen Flüssen orientiert man sich natürlich an der jeweiligen Landessprache. Eine Ausnahme ist aber zum Beispiel die Rhône oder auch die Themse ("Old Father Thames").

Comment: In Frankreich ist es gemischt, wobei die meisten großen Flüsse weiblich sind.  http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Fl%C3%BCsse_in_Frankreich#Nach_L.C3.A4nge

Comment: Gut, dass Du Dein Kommentar in eine Antwort geändert hast, Stefan.

Comment: Es gibt definitv mehr weibliche als männliche Flüsse. An männlichen (über 100 km Länge) nämlich außer den genannten Rhein, Main, Inn, Lech und Neckar noch der Koch, der Regen und der Rhin. Das wars, alle anderen sind weiblich.

Comment: @ingmar der Koch**er**, bitte.

Answer (score 2):

1. Die folgenden Flüsse entstammen alle der Wikipedia [Liste der längsten Flüsse der Erde](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_l%C3%A4ngsten_Fl%C3%BCsse_der_Erde), sind weiblich und liegen außerhalb Europas:

   - Sibirien bzw. Russland östlich des Urals: Angara, Tunguska, Kolyma, Indigirka, Chatanga, Schilka, Aleseja, Jana, Amga, Pjassina, Tawda, Tassejewa, Marcha, Irtysch, Om, Maja, Tura, Birjussa
   - Indien: Yamuna, Krishna
   - Kaukasus: Kura
2. Das in Nordafrika gelegene Wadi Draa ist als absolute Ausnahme sächlich.
3. Zu der oben im Edit hinzugefügten Vermutung, dass *ausländische Flüsse mit Endung -a oder -e feminin sind* finden sich ebenfalls ein paar Gegenbeispiele:

   - Sämtliche Flüsse in Amerika, die mit Rio beginnen: Rio Paraná, Rio Madeira, Rio Grande,...
   - Amudarja und Syrdarja (Zentralasien)
   - Luvua (Zentralafrika)
   - Brahmaputra (Indien)

*Anmerkung:* Eigentlich wollte ich auf [Namen von Flüssen außerhalb Europas: alle maskulin?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/52955/namen-von-fl%C3%BCssen-au%C3%9Ferhalb-europas-alle-maskulin) antworten, allerdings wurde die Frage mit Verweis auf diese hier geschlossen..

Answer (score 1):

In den anderen Antworten wurde schon erklärt, dass und warum durchaus nicht alle Flüsse im deutschen Sprachraum weiblich sind. Allerdings sind in der Tat die allermeisten außereuropäischen Flüsse männlich. Das dürfte einfach daran liegen, dass diese Flussnamen erst vor kurzem ins Deutsche aufgenommen wurden, so dass ihnen ein deutsches Geschlecht zugewiesen wurde. Folgendes ist meine Spekulation auf der Basis von angelesenem linguistischem Wissen.

(1) Neue Fremdwörter erhalten soweit möglich meist dasselbe Geschlecht, wie die Mehrheit vergleichbarer Wörter bzw. wie der offensichtlichste Oberbegriff. (2) Neue Fremdwörter aus romanischen oder germanischen Sprachen erhalten allerdings davon abweichend oft das Geschlecht, das sie in der Ursprungssprache haben. (Zu Fremdwörtern slawischen Ursprungs kann ich nichts sagen.)

Die *Seine* ist im Deutschen gemäß Regel (2) weiblich, weil sie es im Französischen ist. Bei außereuropäischen Flüssen und bei Flüssen in Gegenden, deren Sprachen den Deutschsprachigen weniger vertraut sind, hilft dieses Kriterium aber nicht weiter. Weil *Fluss* männlich ist, ist auch *Nilfluss* männlich, und es ist naheliegend, dass gemäß Regel (1) auch *Nil* männlich ist. Nachdem erst einmal die Mehrheit der außereuropäischen Flüsse auf diese Weise als männlich festgelegt war, entstand die Erwartung, dass alle wenig bekannten ausländischen Flüsse männlich sind.

Answer (score 0):

Wie der Hinweis auf die Ausnahme wegen Endungen in *-a* oder *-e* schon andeutet, lässt sich ansatzweise eine Regel formulieren, die Stammbildung in Indo-Europäischen Sprachen betreffend. Ob für Flüsse ein eigenständiges Ableitungsmorphem existiert, bzw. ob viele der bezeichneten Flüsse einer Alt-Europäischen Hydronomie wie der Hans Krahes entspringen, die widerum von Harald Bichlmeier mehrfach kritisiert wurde, sei dahingestellt.

Wie auch bei die Bäume bspw. *Erle, Eiche, Buche, Tanne, Fichte, Pinie*, etc. deskriptive Wortstämme einundieselbe Ableitung erhalten, verhalten sich Flussnamen regelmäßig in ähnlicher Weise. Es deutet einiges darauf hin, dass nicht nur -e sondern -el(e) entscheidend für Flüsse war, was sich bei 'die Elbe' so gar im Wortstamm niederzuschlagen scheint, vgl. weiters Mosel, Weichsel (latinisiert *Vistula*), Saale. Die Donau, Lateinisch Danube stimmt denn auch mit der Elbe hinsichtlich der Ableitung überein, wobei auch Slavisch *-ova* naheliegt, vgl. *Moldova, Moldau*, während das Vorderglied mit 'der Don' verglichen wird. (zur Elbe siehe [Bichlmeier, Blazek, Elbe - zu den Quellen eines Hydronyms](Elbe - zu den Quellen eines Hydronyms)).

Da passt es auch, dass Schutzpatronin der Quellflüsse weiblich sein mögen, wie die Sequana der Seine zugeschrieben wurde (s. [*seik^(w)- "to pour"](https://www.academia.edu/38197759/The_Old_Norse_theonym_S%C3%ADgyn_seikw_n_i%C3%A9h_she_of_the_pouring_Vedic_Sanskrit_s%C3%A9can%C4%AB_pouring_the_Celtic_river_name_and_theonym_S%C4%93quana_present_day_river_Seine_France_and_Proto_Indo_European_seikw_pour_Loki_and_Fire_n_2_); PS: anders die [die Antwort oben von @Splattne] bzgl. Aenus u.s.w.).

Für Flüsse, deren Namen Lehnworte sind, bspw. für den Amazonas kann das natürlich nicht gelten. Auch der Rhein ist vermutlich aus einer keltischen Sprache entlehnt, die dort vor den Germanen heimisch war und wohl eigentlich das Quellgebiet bezeichnete (s. Wikipedia, dort "brook"). Gerade bei Grenzflüssen ist eine bilinguale Herleitung naheliegend, vgl. die Oder, Obersorbisch "Wódra", d. h. Wasser, bei Ptolomey aber noch "Συήβος" (Suebos; Latin Suevus), was nicht unähnlich der Herleitung zur Vistula von "*u̯eis-" (s. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vistula)) aber offensichtlich mit dem Volksstamm der Suebi in Zusammenhang gebracht wurde.

Für den Rhein wie auch andere Lehnworte wird die übliche Frage nach einer Regel für den Genus eingedeutschter Worte nicht generell zu beantworten sein (vgl. der/die/das Joghurt). Der Rhein reimt sich mit der Schein, der Verein, der Wein, der *Main*, daran wird es wohl liegen.