# Gender of German rivers?

Tags: gender, article, place-name

I am curious whether there is a rule when it comes to the grammatical gender of river names.

As I have understood it, non-German rivers are using *der* as an article, unless we are talking about those that end with *e* or *a,* in which case the article is *die.*

Comment: Related (in German): http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1933/genus-der-fl%c3%bcsse-eine-komische-regel

Comment: Die Donau, die Rednitz, die Pegnitz, die Rezat, die Roth, die Lahn, die Ohm, ...

Comment: Der [Inn](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inn) (Österreich), der  [Lech](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lech) (Tirol und Südbayern), der [Rhein](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhein).

Comment: Die Mosel, die Saar. Flüsse ändern auch m.W. nicht das Geschlecht, wenn sie Grenzen kreuzen, was sie nicht selten tun.

Answer (score 11):

The bottom line is you'd need a full historical record of each hydronym you'd like to analyze.

I cite http://m.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/a-364172.html

> Das Geschlecht von Flüssen lässt sich leider nicht nach Regeln bestimmen. Jeder Flussname hat seine eigene Geschichte, und deren Ursprung liegt meistens im Nebel frühester Zeiten verborgen und ist oft nur mühsam zu rekonstruieren.

For starters:

- when was the name given
- who gave the name (Germanic? Celtic? Romantic?)
- cultural view of water at time named
- other existing names given around the same period and their genders.
  -etc.

As you see, these things could *possibly* be predicted, but there is not any provable blanket rule that would cover any more cases than those you have described. I'd be both happy and surprised to see someone claim that they have discovered such a rule!

Die Elbe
der Rhein
die Donau
der Inn

der Glan ([Celtic](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glan_(Nahe)))

die Glan ([Celtic](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glan_(Gurk)))

Answer (score 1):

Die folgenden deutschen (mit Österreich und Südtirol) Flüsse (über 100 km Länge) sind männlich: der Rhein, der Main, der Inn, der Lech, der Neckar, der Kocher, der Regen, der Rhin und der Eisack. Alle anderen sind weiblich.

Bei ausländischen Flüssen muss man sich an die jeweiligen Landessprache halten, sie sind aber, wenn sie nicht auf -e (die Seine) oder -a (die Wolga) enden, tendenziell männlich.

Comment: Es fließen der Sile, der Idice und der Chiese durch Italien, ebenso der Savena und der Marecchia.

Comment: Es fließen die Lena in Russland und der Lena in Portugal.

Comment: Und gerade noch im Spiegelartikel (siehe Antwort von macmadness86) gelesen: Wir halten uns auch nicht an die Landessprache, denn _die Rhone_ zum Beispiel heißt auf Französisch _le Rhône_.

Comment: Welcher Teil von _tendenziell_ war missverständlich? Prinzipiell ging es aber um deutsch(sprachig)e Flüsse, und da gilt das Gesagte.

Comment: @Ingmar, Der missverständliche Teil ist, dass *tendenziell* in dem Satz nach dem Komma steht und vor dem Komma ein *muss*.

Comment: In den meisten Sprachen (und auch im Deutschen eine gewisse Zeit) ist/war es üblich, Flüsse mit *FlussName Fluss/River* bzw. *Rio FlussName* zu bezeichnen. Dadurch wird beim Übertragen das Genus männlich, selbst wenn die Gattungsbezeichnung später wieder weggelassen wird. Bei Deutschen Flüssen trat dann das gedachte Geschlecht des Namens wieder hervor, bei ausländischen Flüssen nicht im selben Ausmaß (gute Beispiele finde ich nur in Frankreich und Osteuropa/Russland).

Comment: Deutschsprachige Flüsse gibt es gar nicht. Zumindest die, mit denen ich gesprochen habe, sprachen kein Wort Deutsch.

Comment: @userunknown: Du bist sooo lustig. Not.

Comment: @Ingmar: Macht nix, hauptsache es ist lehrreich. Der Rio Grande endet übrigens auch auf E und ist im dt. dennoch männlich.