# Definite articles - cities, lakes

Tags: definite-article, place-name

I read the following title in one of the newspapers:

> Neue Parkvorschriften **im** Simbacher Ortskern

In my workbook it says that town names do not have a definite article if they are unmodified - so why does it say ***im*** Simbacher? Shouldn't it be ***in*** Simbacher?

And another question:

> Spittal **an der** Drau

but

> Frankfurt **am** Main

What's the difference (I assume it has something to do with the exact location of the place)?

Comment: "im" refers to "Ortskern", not to the town name "Simbach". Drau and Main are rivers, not lakes, and rivers have their own gender.

Answer (score 12):

Your first assumption would be correct, if there wasn't that last word of the sentence...

The sentence reads:

> Neue Parkvorschriften im Ortskern

and **Simbacher** is only a descriptive attribute to the noun **Ortskern**

And regarding Drau and Main: There are complete dissertations that try to find out the rules, why some rivers in Germany are male and some are female.

Just read [this thread here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33748/gender-of-german-rivers) for more details about that question

Comment: Thank you very much, I just discovered it: der Main, but die Drau. Thank you again for the explanation!

Comment: @podlasica Did you know that you can mark an answer as _accepted_, if it satisfies your question? You just have to click the check mark next to the up- and down-arrows.