# Genders of place names "Die Niagarafälle"

Tags: article

I was reading about Geography in German and the following sentence appeared:

> Die Niagarafälle sind bekannte Wasserfälle zwischen den USA und Kanada.

Now, with specific nouns regarding places (Niagara Falls above) I was thinking

**Do all nouns related to a location have the same gender i.e. "Die" or is it case specific i.e. they vary for each noun?**

I haven't been able to find a convenient answer thus far.

Comment: See also [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1933/genus-der-fl%C3%BCsse-eine-komische-regel/1934#1934) about gender of rivers in germany

Comment: *Niagarafälle* is plural (singular: der Fall, plural: die Fälle). So the *die* is there not because of gender but because of the plural.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The gender of Niagara Falls in German is not that of the proper noun "Niagara" (whatever that might be), but rather that of a "normal"  noun - "der Fall" (m), or here in the plural, "die Fälle".

German (like English) often adds a "normal" noun to the proper noun of remote places to make sure people know what we're talking about - The gender of the whole name is then that of the "normal" noun like in

- der Berg Sinai
- der See Genezareth
- der Sambesi-Fluss
- das Kaspische Meer
- die Wüste Gobi

Comment: Brilliant. Such a simple explanation that I can't seem to find anywhere else as clear as yours. Cheers!

Comment: And those "normal" nouns often don't even have to be there. It's still *der Sinai*, *der Sambesi* or *die Gobi*.

Comment: @Janka Dangerous: *der Himalaya* vs. *das Himalaya-Gebirge*

Comment: Maybe a slight addition: "Fall" is a little bit special in that it is a shortened form of the noun that would be used on its own, "Wasserfall". Without a proper name such as "Niagara" placed in front of "Fall" (or "Fälle"), no-one will know what you are talking about if you just say "Fall" instead of "Wasserfall".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Admittedly, I rarely hear "Fall" (meaning falling water) alone. In an article about Niagara Falls, you might, however, find a lot of occurrences of "Fälle" without the proper name. Example: The Wikipedia Article on "Niagarafälle" contains 11 occurences of "Niagarafälle" and 20 occurrences of "Fälle".