# Namen von Flüssen außerhalb Europas: alle maskulin?

Tags: gender, article

Stimmt die Regel "Namen von Flüssen **außerhalb Europas** sind maskulin"? Fallen euch Ausnahmen ein? Danke.

Comment: **Die Lena** ist ein Strom in Sibirien im asiatischen Teil Russlands.

Comment: Interessant hierzu: https://www.wissenschaft-im-dialog.de/projekte/wieso/artikel/beitrag/wie-kamen-fluesse-zu-ihren-artikeln-die-weser-die-elbe-der-main-der-inn-die-donau-der-nil-wa/

Comment: Und das auch: https://geschichte-wissen.de/blog/fluesse-maennlich-oder-weiblich/

Comment: mir fällt noch *die Yamuna* in Indien als weiblicher Fluss ausserhalb  Europas ein.

Comment: Wie Jankas Antwort schon zeigt, kann hier keinesfalls von einer Regel die Rede sein, allenfalls von einer Faustregel. Übrigens: Was heißt "außerhalb Europas"? Wo ziehst du die Grenze? Die geographischen Abgrenzungen Europas nach Osten (es gab und gibt ja verschiedene Vorschläge dafür) sind allesamt willkürlich. Zählst du die Wolga noch zu Europa, oder nicht mehr? Dann wäre auch sie ein Gegenbeispiel.

Comment: Die Wolga, die Seine, die Themse... und von wegen in Deutschland sind Flüsse feminin, da hätten wir den Main, den Rhein und sicher noch andere.